# Click to change image is changing the wrong one

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on a website that has a lot of movies, and people can choose what movies are they favorite, and for that, I have a star image that can be clicked and when clicked that image will change to another one

Like this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

The problem I have is that the only image that change is the first one, When I click, for example on the star next to the Ratatouille movie, it will change the first star

This is the HTML:

```
const getMovieHtml = (movie) => `<div class="movie">
    <h2>${movie.title}</h2>
    <img onclick="bottonclick()" id="estrelinhas" src="./icons/empty-star.png" alt="estrela vazia" width=40>
    <div class="content">
    <img src="${movie.posterUrl}" alt="${movie.title}" />
    <div class="text">
        <p>${movie.summary}</p>
        <div class="year">${movie.year}</div>
        <div><strong>Directors:</strong> ${movie.director}</div>
        <div><strong>Actors:</strong> ${movie.actors}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>`;
```

And this is the arrow function I used to make the star change:

```
const bottonclick = () => {
  if (document.getElementById("estrelinhas").src.includes("empty-star.png")) {
     document.getElementById("estrelinhas").src = "./icons/filled-star.png";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("estrelinhas").src = "./icons/empty-star.png";
  }
};
```

Comment: Does all the <img> tags have the same ids ?

Comment: It would be preferable to send in your buttonclick method the id of the item being clicked and that way you will be able to toggle the star icon for each individual movie image.

Comment: Yes, they have identical ids, should I make different ids for all the stars?

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida yes use unique ids per page.

Answer (score 1):

ID attributes of HTML elements should be unique. If you don't have unique ID's the code doesn't know which star to update. Read more about IDs here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

To fix this, a solution would be to use a unique identifier for each image, so that when you click "favourite" it knows which star to reference.

Assuming for example that the movie.posterURL is unique you can use that as the ID, however the data from wherever you are getting the movie from might already have a unique identifier that you could pass to the id attribute of the image instead

Your code could look something like this:

```js
const getMovieHtml = (movie) => `<div class="movie">
        <h2>${movie.title}</h2>
        <img onclick="bottonclick(e)" id="${movie.posterUrl}" src="./icons/empty-star.png" alt="estrela vazia" width=40>
        <div class="content">
        <img src="${movie.posterUrl}" alt="${movie.title}" />
        <div class="text">
            <p>${movie.summary}</p>
            <div class="year">${movie.year}</div>
            <div><strong>Directors:</strong> ${movie.director}</div>
            <div><strong>Actors:</strong> ${movie.actors}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;


const buttonClick = (e) => {
  const star = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
  if (star.src.includes("empty-star.png")) {
    star.src = "./icons/filled-star.png";
  } else {
    star.src = "./icons/empty-star.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: What should I put inside the parenthesis on buttonclick( ) in the HTML function?

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida You can pass ```e```. Because first argument is event in case on events. Clicking on a button is an event. Name that argument anything.

Comment: You should pass the event. `e` is just a shorthand reference for the event object which is the first argument, the event in this case is your img element which contains properties such as the target.id, so by putting `e` inside of buttonClick() you can access that specific element and update/modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

beacuse you getElementById, so you not take all containers,
but you get 1, first, 
change getElementById for querySelectorAll and give there some id,

to localizate in DOM ,

```
buttonClick(e)
```

and in

```
function buttonClick(e) {
   e.target.value/id/or something
}
```